# HTTP status code for upsert (insert/update) endpoint

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes

I have a single `PUT` endpoint which creates/replace an entity and don't need to return a `Location` header or any entity body.

Does it makes sense to always return `204` (No Content) or should it be `201` if it's a new entity and `204` if it replaces the entity?

Comment: For error statuses see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685576/what-http-status-code-should-i-return-for-post-when-no-resource-is-created

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Status codes are meant to *indicate the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the request*. There are two scenarios here:

- If a resource has been **created** as result of the request, it makes sense to return `201`. A `Location` header could also be returned to identify the newly created resource. If no `Location` header is returned by server, the client will assume that the newly created resource is identified by the effective request URI.
- If a resource has been **modified** with the representation sent in the request payload, then `204` or `200` are suitable status codes. With the latter, you could return a representation of the new state of the resource.

Some relevant quotes from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.3.4.  PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload. [...]
>
> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the `PUT` successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the user agent by sending a `201` (Created) response.  If the target resource does have a current representation and that representation is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed representation, then the origin server MUST send either a `200` (OK) or a `204` (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the request. [...]

> [**6.3.1.  200 OK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)
>
> The `200` (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded. The payload sent in a `200` response depends on the request method. For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> [...]
>
> `PUT`, `DELETE`:  a representation of the status of the action;
>
> [...]

> [**6.3.2.  201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.  The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI. [...]

> [**6.3.5.  204 No Content**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)
>
> The `204` (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.  Metadata in the response header fields refer to the target resource and its selected representation after the requested action was applied. [...]

Comment: Yeah, but in my case this endpoint basically is a migration endpoint from one service to another, so the service that doing the call already know the object, and I don't need a get request to return  a `Location` header.

Because if i need to do that in 1 endpoint (upsert) then there is an `if` condition to see was it a create or update, and depending on that I return the response code.

I searched a little bit and found that `204` could fit if I don't return any content, so what do you think now with these extra info :)?

Comment: @AhmedAlaaEl-Din I have added some details to my answer. You may not need to return a `Location` header: In this case the client will assume that the newly created resource is identified by the effective request URI. Bear in mind that HTTP status codes are meant to _indicate the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the request_. Having said that and assuming that you want to conform to the `PUT` semantics, you should return `201` when a resource has been _created_ and `204` or `200` when a resource has been _modified_.